# Workweek completion

Tags: code-golf, date

I work from Monday to Friday. I start my day at `8:12` and have lunch from `12:00` to `12:42`. My workday ends at `16:30`.

If you are wondering why 8:12 and 12:42:

- `8:00` is the goal, but I never actually make it
- `12:42` because I take 45 minute breaks, but this works better for the challenge spec

---

#### Challenge

Write a function or full program that returns the smallest fraction of time I have worked and still need to work for the current week. The interval you must use is 6 min.

Each day has 76 six-minute intervals

---

#### Examples

```
Monday 02:00 -> 0/1  
Monday 08:24 -> 1/190  
Monday 18:00 -> 1/5  
Saturday xx:xx -> 1/1  

Monday 08:17 -> 0/1  
Monday 08:18 - Monday 08:23 -> 1/380
```

---

#### Scoring

Shortest code win but golfing languages get a *3 multiplier.

- Pyth
- CJam
- GolfScript

(note to self: add more)

---

**Edit:** I've lowered the modifier, but I will not remove it. Some languages have some overhead like variable declaration and other long keywords; `function` ,`return`, etc. I don't want to discourage someone from writing the skeleton of a method in their chosen language because it's longer than a complete CJam answer.

Comment: perl,j,k,piet,APL etc.

Comment: 4.5 is a very high multiplier. Python and Mathematica (and some other) languages can easily come withing 2-3 x of CJam for non-trivial challenges.

Comment: -1 for arbitrary language bias.

Comment: The point here should only be code size on similar challenges as this is code-golf.

Comment: Should we change this to [code-challenge], then?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the incomplete description/list of what constitutes a golfing language makes it impossible to objectively score solutions.

Comment: I would just remove the golf-lang restriction. (I'm also giving it a +1 for the rest of the question, by the way)

Answer (score 2):

## C++: 204 bytes

**g++ 4.9.2**

```c
int f(char*a){int d=380,n=*a-'M'?*a-'W'?*a-'F'?*a-'S'?a[1]-'u'?3:1:5:4:2:0,m,h;sscanf(a,"%*s%d:%d",&h,&m);h=(m=h*10+m/6-82)<38?m:m>83?76:m-7;n=min(d,n*76+max(h,0));m=__gcd(n,d);printf("%d/%d\n",n/m,d/m);}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/OpbxUb)

Same as old answer, just replaced 5 ternary conditions of form `a==b?c:d` with `a-b?d:c` to save 1 byte each condition. Rest of the explanation remains same.

---

Old answer:

## <del>C++: 210 bytes</del>

<del>int f(char*a){int d=380, n=*a=='M'?0:*a=='W'?2:*a=='F'?4:*a=='S'?5:a[1]=='u'?1:3,m,h;sscanf(a,"%*s%d:%d",&h,&m);h=(m=h*10+m/6-82)83?76:m-7;n=min(d,n*76+max(h,0));m=__gcd(n,d);printf("%d/%d\n",n/m,d/m);}</del>

[<del>Live demo</del>](http://ideone.com/gAuqc3)

## Explanations

```c
int f(char* a) {  // Function name. Returning int instead of void to save one char
    int d=380;  // denominator

    int n= *a == 'M' ?  // Number of days
               0 :  // Monday
               *a == 'W' ?
                   2 :  // Wednesday
                   *a == 'F' ?
                       4 :  // Friday
                       *a == 'S' ?
                           5 :  // Saturday or Sunday
                           a[1] == 'u' ?
                                 1 :  // Tuesday
                                 3;   // Thurdays

    int m, h;  // Minutes and hours

    sscanf(a, "%*s%d:%d", &h, &m);  // %*s - Skip day, %d:%d - Read hour and min

    h= (
         m=h*10+m/6-82  // Calculate (h * 60 + m) / 6 - (8 * 60 + 12) / 6 
       ) < 38 ? m       // Before lunch
              : m>83 ? 76  // If it is past end of day 76) clamp to 76
                     :m-7; // After lunch, subtract lunch time

    n = min(d,                  // numerator (n) can not be more than denominator
            n * 76 + max(h,0) ); // Number of day * units (6 min) per day + units of current day (from time) clamped to 0 if negative

    m=__gcd(n, d);  // Find gcd to get normalized form of rational number

    printf("%d/%d\n", n/m, d/m);  // Print the result
}  // Function ends
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!  Correct answers are great - but you'll garner more votes if you explain what's clever about your solution.  There are various ways to do that; one that's popular is a formatted, annotated version of the same code.  Any chance of obliging?  Thanks.  It's good to see you here; happy golfing!

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks for the welcome words and the suggestion. I looked at a few posts to understand what you mean. I will add similar description in my code also.

Comment: @TobySpeight Done

Comment: Where does `__gcd` come from?

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 `std::__gcd` is exposed in `C++` library in gcc compilers.

Answer (score 0):

## Python - 195 bytes

Very simple, uses fractions library for simplest terms. Had a Pyth solution, but the `*4.5` was too much.

```
from fractions import*
z=raw_input()
Q=input()
n=("SMTWTF".index(z[0])-1if z[0]!='T'else"uh".index(z[1])*2+1)*76
Q=max(Q[0]*10+Q[1]/6-82,0)
print Fraction(n+(min(Q, 38)if Q<45 else min(Q-7,76)),380)
```

Takes input in two lines, the time as a tuple, since no input format was specified.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>201</s> 191 bytes

```js
f=i=>{z=(a,b)=>b?z(b,a%b):a,i=/(\w+) (\d+):(\d+)/.exec(i),t=+i[3]/6+i[2]*10-82;t=i[0][0]=='S'?380:'neduit'.indexOf(i[1][2])*76+(t<0?0:t>82?76:t>45?t-7:t>38?38:t);g=z(t,380);return+t/g+'/'+380/g}
```

#### ECMAScript 5: <s>223</s> 214 bytes

```js
function f(i){z=function(a,b){return!b?a:z(b,a%b)},i=/(\w+) (\d+):(\d+)/.exec(i),t=+i[3]/6+i[2]*10-82;t=i[0][0]=='S'?380:'neduit'.indexOf(i[1][2])*76+(t<0?0:t>82?76:t>45?t-7:t>38?38:t);g=z(t,380);return+t/g+'/'+380/g}
```

Ungolfed

```js
function f(input) {
    var greatestCommonDivisor = function (a, b) {
        // From https://stackoverflow.com/a/17445304/404623
        return !b ? a : greatestCommonDivisor(b, a % b);
    };

    // Get input from string
    var input = /(\w+) (\d+):(\d+)/.exec(input);

    // Parse time relative to day
    var t = Number(input[3]) / 6 + Number(input[2]) * 10 - 82;

    var m, g, divisor;

    if (input[0][0] == 'S') {
        // Weekend - week is over
        m = 380;
    } else {
        if (t < 0) {
            // Before start of work day
            m = 0;
        } else if (t > 82) {
            // After end of work day
            m = 76;
        } else if (t > 45) {
            // After lunch
            m = t - 7;
        } else if (t > 38) {
            // During lunch
            m = 38;
        } else {
            m = t;
        }

        // Indices correspond to third letter of day of week
        m += 'neduit'.indexOf(input[1][2]) * 76;
    }

    // Find common divisor
    divisor = greatestCommonDivisor(m, 380);

    // Return value
    return m / divisor + '/' + 380 / divisor;
}
```

```js
function f(i) {
  z = function(a, b) {
    return !b ? a : z(b, a % b)
  }, i = /(\w+) (\d+):(\d+)/.exec(i), t = +i[3] / 6 + i[2] * 10 - 82;
  t = i[0][0] == 'S' ? 380 : 'neduit'.indexOf(i[1][2]) * 76 + (t < 0 ? 0 : t > 82 ? 76 : t > 45 ? t - 7 : t > 38 ? 38 : t);
  g = z(t, 380);
  return t / g + '/' + 380 / g
}

['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'].forEach(function(d) {
  var str;
  for (var h = 8; h < 17; h++) {
    for (var m = 0; m < 60; m += 6) {
      str = d + ' ' + (h < 10 ? '0' + h : h) + ':' + (m < 10 ? '0' + m : m);
      document.body.innerHTML += str + ' -> ' + f(str) + '<br>';
    }
  }
});
```

Assumes that Sunday is the last day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, 254 bytes

This is just a port of my JavaScript answer. Due to PHP's odd behaviour with ternary operators, parentheses are necessary.

```php
function z($a,$b){return$b?z($b,$a%$b):$a;}function f($q){preg_match('/(\w+) (\d+):(\d+)/',$q,$i);$t=$i[3]/6+$i[2]*10-82;$t=$i[0][0]=='S'?380:strpos('neduit',$i[1][2])*76+($t<0?0:($t>82?76:($t>45?$t-7:($t>38?38:$t))));$g=z($t,380);return$t/$g.'/'.(380/$g);}
```